Chain rule when mixed partial multiplied by first order partial
Given
$$
r = \frac{{\partial s}}{{\partial t}}
$$
If we take the partial derivative of $r$ with respect to $u$ $\frac{{\partial r}}{{\partial u}}$ and multiply it by $\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial v}}$ we have by the chain rule that
$$
\frac{{\partial r}}{{\partial u}}\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial v}} = \frac{{\partial r}}{{\partial v}}
$$
However from what I can find using $$\frac{{\partial r}}{{\partial u}} = \frac{{\partial \left( {\frac{{\partial s}}{{\partial t}}} \right)}}{{\partial u}} = \frac{{\partial ^2 s}}{{\partial u\partial t}}$$
and again multiplying by $\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial v}}$ we would have
$$\frac{{\partial \left( {\frac{{\partial s}}{{\partial t}}} \right)}}{{\partial u}}\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial v}} = \frac{{\partial ^2 s}}{{\partial u\partial t}}\frac{{\partial u}}{{\partial v}} \ne \frac{{\partial ^2 s}}{{\partial v\partial t}}
$$
I am trying to prove the derivation of an equation that seems to require that the last result with the second order mixed partial being equal to the quantity before it but from what I find online it is not. Is this correct and, if so, why doesn't it seem consistent with the result when I use $r$?

As long as the partial derivatives commute at $s$, i.e. $\frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial u \partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 s}{\partial t \partial u} $, for example because all partial derivatives are continuous (Schwarz's theorem), the last equation should be correct in my opinion. Then simply use the chain rule backwards.
